# can css animation get a shorthand of -moz-animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I know css animation have a shorthand of -webkit-animation:

```
div {
-webkit-animation-name: example;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;  
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate; 
}
```

we can use the shorthand for the animation code:

```
div {-webkit-animation: example 1s ease 0 2 alternate;}
```

But it seems that -moz-animation didn't work in my experiment. Is that true?

```
div {-moz-animation: example 1s ease 0 2 alternate;} //did not work in my experiment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a -moz-animation extension.

here is the full list of extensions for Mozilla browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Comment: I have updated my question,in the mozilla page, I have not seen anything about shorthand of -moz-animation, please help me,thanks.